# How can I efficiently search a field for flipped word order?

Tags: php, arrays, unique

I have the following array.

```
$arr = array('foo','bar','foo-bar','abc','def','abc-def','ghi','abc-def-ghi');
```

I'm given a new string to decide to add to the array or not. If the string is already in the array, don't add it.  If it is not in the array in its current form, but in a flipped word form is found, don't add it.

How should I accomplish this?

Examples:

```
'foo'     —->  N  - Do NOT add, already found
'xyz'     —->  Y  - Add, this is new
'bar-foo' —->  N  - Do NOT add, already found in the flipped form 'foo-bar'
'ghi-jkl' —->  Y  - Add, this is new
```

What do you recommend?

Comment: One quick thought is alphabetizing/sorting the values before adding to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exclude items whose elements ('abc','ghi', etc.) are contained in another order and not only reversed, you could do:

```
$arr = array('foo','bar','foo-bar','abc','def','abc-def','ghi','abc-def-ghi');

function split_and_sort($str) {
    $partsA = explode('-', $str);
    sort($partsA);
    return $partsA;
}
$arr_parts = array_map('split_and_sort', $arr);

$tests = array('foo','xyz','bar-foo','ghi-jkl');
$tests_parts = array_map('split_and_sort', $tests);

foreach($tests_parts as $test) {
    if( !in_array($test, $arr_parts)) {
        echo "adding: " . join('-', $test) . "\n";
        $arr[] = join('-', $test);
    }
    else {
        echo "skipping: " . join('-', $test) . "\n";
    }
}
var_export($arr);
```

which outputs:

```
skipping: foo
adding: xyz
skipping: bar-foo
adding: ghi-jkl
array (
  0 => 'foo',
  1 => 'bar',
  2 => 'foo-bar',
  3 => 'abc',
  4 => 'def',
  5 => 'abc-def',
  6 => 'ghi',
  7 => 'abc-def-ghi',
  8 => 'xyz',
  9 => 'ghi-jkl',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Heres a suggestions on one way you can try...

for each string in $arr, reverse it as push into another array called $rev_arr

then...

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($arr as $arr_1) $new_array[$arr_1] = true; // just set something

foreach ($rev_arr as $arr_2) $new_array[$arr_2] = true; // do also for reverse
```

now you can check what you want to do based on

```
if ( isset($new_arr[ $YOUR_TEST_VARIABLE_HERE ]) ) { // match found
}
```